# How to reset password in Azure AD user?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am using azure AD for my application authentication. User is crated successfully in Azure AD. And user can login with password. My requirement is how user can reset their own password. When a user forgot their password, how they can reset their own password within my application. Is there any graph api available?

Comment: You need to update the User object from your back-end with application-level permissions to reset any user's password. As far as I know, you'll need to add the app's service principal to an admin role manually with e.g. PowerShell to do this.

Comment: You'll also have to consider the security aspects of doing this, e.g. the user needs to somehow prove who they are before you reset the password. Since otherwise you'd be allowing anyone to reset someone else's password.

Comment: Is there any graph api can use for reset password ?

Comment: Microsoft Graph API, check out the User entity update operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Resetting a user's password**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/users-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#ResetUserPassword) is a special case of the update user operation. Specify the **passwordProfile** property for the [User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity). The request contains a valid `PasswordProfile` object that specifies a password that satisfies the tenant’s password complexity policy. The password policy typically imposes constraints on the complexity, length, and re-use of a password. For more information, see the [PasswordProfile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#passwordprofile-type) topic.

You can reset a user's password by PATCHing the user object:

```
PATCH https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}?api-version=1.6

{
    "passwordProfile": {
        "password": "{password}",
        "forceChangePasswordNextLogin": false
    },
    "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"
}
```

**Preparation**:

1.Switch the Directory that you have admin authority.Add **New User** in Azure AD. Get the username and password.

**Note**: When you set up username, behind @ is your whole directory name. When the first time login, you need to change the password.

[image]

2.Go to the Native App you have registered, add the permission  **Access the directory as the signed-in user** to the app.
[image]
**Note**:Either delegated scope `User.ReadWrite.All` or `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` is required to reset a user's password. In addition to the correct scope, the `signed-in` user would need sufficient privileges to reset another user's password.

3.Now, you could refer to the code as below:

```
var graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net/";
var tenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var password = "xxxxxxxxx";
var servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceId);
var serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantId);
string aadInstance = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/oauth2/token";
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance, false);

UserPasswordCredential credential = new UserPasswordCredential(username, password);
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(graphResourceId, clientId, credential).Result;
var accessToken = authenticationResult.AccessToken;
HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
string url = "https://graph.windows.net/" + tenantId + "/users/" + username + "?api-version=1.6";
var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, url);
request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authenticationResult.AccessToken);
var body = "{\"passwordProfile\": {\"password\": \"YourNewPassword\",\"forceChangePasswordNextLogin\": false},\"passwordPolicies\":\"DisablePasswordExpiration\"}";
request.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
HttpResponseMessage response = http.SendAsync(request).Result;
```

4.Here is the output:
[image]